# Dot fade pattern brush is 'squished' in corners, how do i solve this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created a pattern brush in illustrator, and i need it to follow this path (below) evenly, however it seems to be getting 'squished' into the corners and the dots are stretching.

Is there a way i can stop this happening so the dot fade follows around the path evenly?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a pattern brush you can define the corner tile. Just create your corner tile and <kbd>alt</kbd> + drag it to the corner tile of your brush in the brushes panel.

One thing to keep in mind is that your normal tile and corner tile should be the same height to keep them aligned, you can add a transparent rectangle around your tiles to make up the extra space:

[image: Pattern brush tiles]

I made this manually and very quickly with a bunch of circles so the alignment is off on the corners, but thats down to my sloppy placement, not a problem with the brush:

[image: Pattern brush]

This does mean you have to predefine your corner radius, which isn't ideal, but it's the only way to prevent the distortion on corners *using pattern brushes*.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't a way to do this using a brush. The size of the curve and the thickness of the border means that the outside of the the border has to cover more ground than the inside, so whatever pattern you use as your border has to warp with it.

While it doesn't solve your 'squished corners' problem, you can achieve a similar effect by using an **Inner Glow** and a **Color Halftone**.

[image]

1. Draw your shape, give it rounded corners and a white fill.
2. Go `Effect > Stylize > Inner Glow` and give your shape a black inner glow. Set the blending mode to Normal, the opacity to 100%.
3. Now select your shape and go `Effect > Pixelate > Color Halftone`.
4. Finally, select your shape and go `Edit > Edit Colors > Convert to Grayscale` to convert it from a four-colour halftone to a two-colour one.

The drawback is that this results in a raster pattern, not a vector one, as it uses a Photoshop effect inside Illustrator.